# Response pipeline couldn't transform data class using gson - Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I really apologize if this question has been asked before, I'll delete it as soon as someone posts a duplicate, but why does this fail ?

```
package com.example

import com.example.data.TestObject
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.features.CallLogging
import io.ktor.features.Compression
import io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.features.DefaultHeaders
import io.ktor.gson.gson
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty
import java.text.DateFormat

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(Compression)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
            setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG)
            setPrettyPrinting()
        }
    }

    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/test") {
                val instance = TestObject()
                call.respond(instance)
            }
        }
    }
    server.start(true)
}
```

my TestObject :

```
data class TestObject(val name: String = "John", val additional: String = "Doe")
```

and my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1'
mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-apache:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version"
    testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version"
}
```

The only exception I get is this :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Response pipeline couldn't transform 'class com.example.data.TestObject' to the OutgoingContent
    at io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationResponse$Companion$setupSendPipeline$1.invokeSuspend(BaseApplicationResponse.kt:271)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationResponse$Companion$setupSendPipeline$1.invoke(BaseApplicationResponse.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:268)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:67)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:141)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:161)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:27)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt$module$server$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:48)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt$module$server$1$1$1.invoke(Application.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:268)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(PipelineContext.kt:67)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:141)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:161)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:27)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:147)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:34)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:99)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
```

The project does run and i'm able to access different routes of different get requests, but using Gson to serialize my responses just doesn't seem to work ?

Any help is really appreciated, I started out a few hours ago :)

Comment: I've a feeling your modules are configured correctly and ktor probably doesn't know that you've configured gson for content negotiation. Try specifying in the application.conf file.

Comment: Also, doesn't make sense to use both embeddedServer and EngineMain. Use either but not both. Get rid of embedded server in the module and specify the module in the modules property in your application.conf. Things should work then.

Comment: @dhaliman i had an answer here at some point, but people downvoted it, either due to it being incorrect or perhaps out of spite, i'm not sure :) when i removed the embedded server it started working. feel free to write it as an answer